# How to conditionally remove value attribute using react

Tags: reactjs, conditional-formatting

I want to remove value property from input field in react. How can I achieve this?

For ex. I want to remove value property from below input field

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} />
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the *property* or just reset/clear its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the value attribute completely, you can have its key and value come from an object to be spread onto the element

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2vreml

In this example, only input 5 will have no `value` attribute

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value1: 'React',
    value2: null,
    value3: undefined,
    input4: { type: 'text', value: '123' },
    input5: { type: 'text' }
  };


  render() {
    const { value1, value2, value3, input4, input5 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={value1} />
        <input type="text" value={value2} />
        <input type="text" value={value3} />
        <input {...input4} />
        <input {...input5} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting value property undefined conditionally worked for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to handle to show or not value in `input`.
You may have got a flag to handle it.
Then:

```
<input type="text" value={isShow ? this.state.value : ""} />
```